# Python :How to use loc with multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with multiple columns. We need to check if any of the columns has a value 0; if 0 is there we have to add new column with tag.

I tried this :

```
df.loc[df['maths'] == '0', 'mark_student'] = 'fail'
```

This it working for single column, but when I tried it for multiple columns, it's failing

Like this :

```
df.loc[df['maths','chemistry'] == '0', 'mark_student'] = 'fail'

df.loc[df[['maths','chemistry']] == '0', 'mark_student'] = 'fail'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df[['maths','chemistry']] == '0'` returns a data frame, which can't be directly used as boolean index at row level. You can use `.any(1)` to reduce it to a Series and then use it with `.loc`:

```
df.loc[(df[['maths','chemistry']] == '0').any(1), 'mark_student'] = 'fail'
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use () each condition,

```
df.loc[(df['maths'] == 0) & (df['chemistry'] ==  0) & (df['mark_student'] == 'fail')
```